# How to install curl package .deb file in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, deb

I download curl deb file from curl official site : https://curl.haxx.se/. I want to install curl deb file but meet this trouble:

[image]

Please tell e how to fix this trouble. I'm not edit anything on /etc/apt/sources.list. Why this trouble happend to me?

Comment: To muru. I think you wrong something. This a trouble, I do it right, just look my picture capture screen. not don't know how problem.

Comment: @fastestsuperman install those dependency files using `sudo apt-get install ` . If those also need some other dependency, then install those manually too. Why you download deb ? Why not use `sudo apt-get install curl` ?

Comment: is anybody help e fast, please?

Comment: yeah, i know Serg, but I want to test some .deb file but why it don't run in here?

Comment: can anybody help me fast?

Comment: I don't see any `.deb` file links on https://curl.haxx.se/. For Ubuntu and Debian there are just links to the official package repositories of these distros which means you can install curl with just `apt-get install curl`.

Comment: P.S.: The `libcurl3` version [provided for Xenial](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/curl) is currently 7.47 – far newer than the 7.22 you're trying to install.

Comment: -1 for not giving text output

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 has upgraded PHP to 7.0. Just do `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`.

Source: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-curl

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of installing libcurl3 in Ubuntu 16.04 is to install the libcurl3 package from the default Ubuntu repositories like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
```

Instead of installing the latest version of libcurl3 for Ubuntu 16.04, you downloaded an older version of libcurl3 for Ubuntu 12.04 and ran into a problem with a missing dependency package named librtmp0. librtmp0 has been upgraded to librtmp1 in Ubuntu 16.04. You can proceed from here by installing librtmp0 manually. Download librtmp0 for Ubuntu 12.04 from from the official [Download Page for librtmp0_2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/librtmp0/download) webpage and manually install the .deb file. You can also manually install librtmp0 alongside librtmp1.

Run the following command to prevent librtmp0 from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

```
sudo apt-mark hold librtmp0
```